# How does 1-methylcyclohexene reacting with KMnO4 produce 1-methyl-1,2-cyclohexanediol?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am interested in knowing how diols are produced when you introduce a reagent like potassium permanganate to an alkene. What is the mechanism for these reactions? The hydroxyl substituents happens to be at the 1,2 position each time.

Comment: There's a *syn*-addition of $\ce{-OH}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a particular case of syn-dihydroxylation, also known as Wagner reaction. "Syn-dihydroxylation" means that a double bond is cleaved into a single bond and two OH groups are attached to the carbon atoms that were involved into a double bond **from the same side**. Anti-addition is not possible as permanganate anion can't be attached to the double bond from different sides of the bond due to steric reasons. 
There is a [Khan Academy video](https://youtu.be/76KtDSfWnkw?t=387)  that describes the mechanism of this particular addition, but that video is all about different cases of syn-addition.
In brief, the mechanism can be also drawn as following:
[image]